# JAAS get User information

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaas

I used JAAS and I don't know how to get the information about the user id, username .. should I set the values using a ManagedBean, or the JAAS it self provides it.

Comment: Thank you, well I must use it in both JSF and ManagedBeans, Can I get The id to perform other functionalities

Comment: Your JAAS `LoginModule` will perform a login and acquire all information about a user, the relevant parts of which should be placed into the `Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get user information you have to use principals
refer `https://nick-lab.gs.washington.edu/java/jdk1.4.1/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html#SampleLMPrincipal`
you will also get a sample code there
after setting a principal to your subject in your loginmodule you can get the name with the command
`loginContext.getSubject().getPrincipals().iterator().next().getName()`
associate principal to each information and add it to subject while logging in then you can get the user data with the subject.. if anymore doubts comment

Answer (score -3):

The JAAS provide username and does not provide all information, here a suggestion to recover all infromation with ManagedBean and JSP

With JSF you can get all informations about the user like this :

```
    import org.service.UserFacade;
    import org.entity.userEntity;
    import java.security.Principal;
    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class MySessionController {

        @EJB
        private UserFacade userFacade;

        String login;

        public MySessionController() {
            Principal principal = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getUserPrincipal();
            // get login from principal
            login = principal.getName();
            //get all informations of user from EJB : UserFacade
            userEntity user = userFacade.findByLogin(login);
        }
    }
```

With JSP you can get all informations about the user like this :

```
<%@page import="javax.naming.InitialContext"%>
<%@page import="javax.naming.Context"%>
<%@page import="org.service.UserFacade"%>
<%@page import="org.entity.userEntity"%>
<%@page import="java.security.Principal"%>

    <%
        String login;
        Principal loginUser = request.getUserPrincipal();

        // get login from principal
        if (loginUser != null) {
            login = loginUser.getName()
        }

        //get all informations of user from EJB : UserFacade
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        UserFacade userFacade = (UserFacade) c.lookup("java:global/MyProject/MyEjbMoule/UserFacade!org.service.UserFacade");
        userEntity user = userFacade.findByLogin(login);
    %>
```

Comment: The question is about JAAS.